# VBA Auotmation - Closing IE Before IE.Quit Runs Freezes Excel

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation

I have some code which closes IE after some VBA Website Automation (after waiting for a period of time).

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:55"))
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing
```

The problem is that if someone inadvertently closes IE before the IE.Quit code executes, Excel freezes because the IE property no longer exists.

I've tried something like this (please see below code excerpt) but Excel still freezes if it's closed before the timer executes the code (Run-Time error '462', The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable):

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:55"))
If IE Is Nothing Then
    'do nothing
Else
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set doc = Nothing
End If
```

Any ideas or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do, besides trying to swallow whatever error `IE.Quit` might throw - you can do that with `On Error Resume Next`, and then you can do `On Error GoTo 0` after `Set IE = Nothing` (`doc` looks like it should already be out of scope by then though).

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with what Mathieu says. The freeze is due to the waiting is still being executed. Everything you put after `Application.Wait` will be executed after the waiting--which is to say after "the freeze".

You can only add `On Error Resume Next` after `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:55"))` to avoid the error display, but you can't stop the waiting.